# ActionScript 3: How to expand DynamicText automatically?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How do you make a DynamicText spans into 2 lines when the text (dynamically-assigned) is too long.

I want to keep the width, but the height should adjust automatically.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
yourTextField.multiline = true;
```

If the dimensions of the TextField are not enough to house the extra text you may also want to use:

```
yourTextField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
```

which will extend the height of your TextField (but not width as the multiline has been set to true)